# how to Notifications from NodeJS backend App to Flutter Android App?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter

I developed a flutter with node js and my database is MongoDB. I want to send notifications from my server to flutter app users when a document is updated. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do with Firebase Messaging NodeJS SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

Integrate your application with Firebase. After activating Firebase Cloud Messaging, you can make users who will receive notifications get notifications by subscribing to the topic.